# Cannot use most of the devices with WebPack

Tags: webpack, fpga, vivado

I installed Vivado 2020.3 on my new PC. To my knowledge, I can use almost all small FPGAs with WebPack, even though there are product limitations. However, in 2020.3, most of the devices are not available as shown in the following figure. How can I use them such as Artix-7 or Virtex UltraScale+?
[picture of vivado installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbpdP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking in the right place? Are the devices greyed out because they are already installed? Try starting a project and see what parts it lets you select.

Comment: I have Digilent's Arty7 board and Avnet's Ultra96V2 board, so I downloaded the board files from GitHub for each and installed them in the appropriate locations as follows.
C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2020.3\data\boards\board_files [continue]

Comment: Furthermore, during the create project, only the boards I don't have were displayed as shown in the yellow oval on the left, so I pressed the button on the top right to install the Arty7 board and the Ultra96 board, but the result was the same. I thought it was the license that was preventing the board files from appearing even though they were installed.

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiGIS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself. I'm using 2020.3 and it says that only the following FPGAs are supported.

Versal™ AI Core Series :- XCVC1902、XCVC1802
Versal™ Prime Series :- XCVM1802

Therefore, I will be using 2020.2 instead.
[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7tBZ.png)